# Outlook 2016: turn on AutoArchive for ALL folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I did some search but got nothing helpful then I post this question here.
How can we turn on AutoArchive for ALL FOLDER in Outlook 2016? Currently I have >20 mail folder but all of them in on "Do not archive item in this folder" and I don't want to right click 20 times for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Outlook functionality for that. But you do that with free [Set Folder AutoArchive Settings](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderAutoArchive/) utility.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.